# Remove "has stopped working" message windows 8

Tags: windows-8, script, windows-registry, crash

I want to be able to remove the "has stopped working" message that comes up when a program crashes because I am trying to write a script that automatically opens the program back up if it does crash.

I would like the program to automatically close when it crashes instead of showing the message and asking me to "close the program manually".

I have seen tutorials on how to do this for windows 7 but none for windows 8.
Some of the solutions are changing/adding new registry key, can anyone confirm how to remove the dialogue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Disable **Windows Error Reporting (WER)** in Windows 8 from *Action Center settings* in the Control Panel:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Next open *regedit* and navigate to either of the two keys below:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
```

If it's not already present create a REG_DWORD called **Disabled** to enable or disable WER:

```
Possible values:

0 - Enabled (default)
1 - Disabled
```

and another REG_DWORD called **DontShowUI** to enable or disable the WER UI:

```
Possible values:

0 - UI (default)
1 - No UI
```

Reference: [Full list of WER Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638.aspx)